# getting different paths using HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

See the following code. I'm uploading files, Yet i'm getting different results from difference browsers.

Firefox var path = "about.restaurant.jpg"

yet in ie6 path = "D:\dev\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\Website\images\about.restaurant.jpg"

```
 foreach (string file in Request.Files)
 {
        var hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;
        var path = hpf.FileName;
 }
```

I had this issue in MVC2 . Just upgraded to MVC3. Same issue exist.

```
<form action="/Product/SaveUploadImage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="button" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

ah ok i see. so there is method that resolves all this

Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName)